# I'm not able to deploy my MERN App on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, heroku, mern

I'm trying to connect my GitHub account and deploy it on Heroku using GitHub Connect.

I'm getting this error which I'm not able to solve.

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my GitHub repository link  - https://github.com/aquib12377/thehealthykrunch

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained. We're not going to go off-site to dig through code. Please [edit] your `package.json` directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file. You should have a build command. Heroku uses that to build your project.

So in build stage heroku first installs all your node modules and later on it runs `npm run build`. Then finally for deploying `npm start` command is run

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a build command in my *package.json*.

I have another package.json in \frontend folder

Comment: Heroku only access the top level package.json. It won't read your package.json present in frontend folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run command on terminal to check logs and add npm version in your pacage.json

```
 heroku logs --app your_app_name
```

Comment: I checked and replaced the version of node in package.json

Comment: "engines": {
    "node": "16.0.0",
    "npm": "7.24.1"
  },

Comment: Remove proxy from frontend package.json